# Mean Field Games

Tags: game-theory, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to learn mean field games from the Carmona Book, "Probabilistic Theory of Mean Field Games with Applications". There is a fundamental notion of empirical distribution.

The sate $X = (x_1, \cdots, x_n) \in E^n$ where $E$ is a compact metric space. The empirical distribution or probability measure $\overline{\mu}_X^n$ is defined as:

$\overline{\mu}_X^n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n \delta_{x_i}$ where the $\delta_x$ is a unit mass point at $x \in E$.

Other than compactness there is no assumption made on the state space. In what sense is $\overline{\mu}_X^n$ a measure on $E$.

Comment: It has the three defining properties of probability measure

Comment: @Stochs thank you for the response. Yes it is supposed to have the properties of probability measure. The question is how? $X \in E^n$ the triple we are looking at $(E, \sigma (E), \overline{\mu}_X^n)$, so if $A \in \sigma(E)$ what would $\overline{\mu}^n_X (A)$ be?

Comment: $\mu_X^n(A)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{x_i}(A)$. In particular it is a random measure which counts the frequencies of the $x_i's$ in $A$

Comment: Ok I get that, that is the way I understood it. But, does that mean that the normalizing factor $n$ keeps changing? It should be card(E) right? or what am I missing? The number of $x_i$ in $A$ can be larger than $n$. It looks like an indicator function to me, but then again not.

Comment: No the $n$ does not change. Given a $n-$tuple $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ it counts the number of this $x_i's$ in $A$, so it cannot be larger than $n$. Remember it is a random measure and not a measure

Comment: So I see, what is fixed is the n-tuple $X$? so $\mu_X^n(A)$ will at most be 1 if all $x_i \in A$ and $0$ if none belong. If all are in $A$ then the probability is $1$. So $\mu_X^n(E) = 1$ for all $X \in E^n$. Ok that clarifies it quite a bit. Thanks a million for the patience and explaining.